# Gradient for IE6 not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, gradient

I have several divs on a webpage that use the IE css filter to create a gradient effect for the background.

The page is viewed primarily in IE6 (I have no other choice unfortunatly) and displays fine on my development machine. I have also tried viewing the page using IETester and the page also displays fine in IE 5.5 to IE 8.

However, when viewing the page on the "live" machine, the gradients don't show up at all. The browser on the "live" machine is IE 6 with sp3. I have checked the div's and they all have "hasLayout" so that isn't the problem.

Are there any settings within IE that would stop filters working or could anybody suggest any other reasons why they would not be showing up. I can't work out why they work in one version of IE 6 but not another.

Unfortunatly I can't link to any examples.

Thanks

Comment: Could be the browser deciding to switch between quirks/standards mode, which tends to kill most everything css-related pretty quickly.

Comment: We don't want you to link to examples, we want you to post the CSS you're using. :D

Comment: (1.)  clear browsers cache. (2.) Make sure new file is uploaded to server. (3.) view it in other browsers on the machine. this is also a useful gradient tool. http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The code that I'm using is: `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0A284B', endColorstr='#135887');`. Like I said it works fine normally but trying it on the live server totally knocks out all gradients

Comment: Can you use a repeated background image to create the gradient instead?

Comment: Hm.. The `filter` you're using is right for IE. Take Richard Lee's suggestions and clear the cache and ensure you've uploaded the latest css file to the server. Also, may be pertinent to ensure you don't have an ie-specific stylesheet declaring a `background` property that overrides the one with the gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `filter` features of IE are not built into the browser; they are using external libraries (DLLs). This is what the 'progid' part is all about, and also explains why some of them are so clunky.

If those DLLs are not installed on the client machine, then the `filter` styles won't work. If it works in some IE6 machines but not others, then this is almost certainly the problem you're encountering.

Theoretically it should be possible for you to fix the problem by installing the missing DLLs.

However, the problem for you is that if the client is anal enough not to have upgraded their browser from IE6 yet, then it's pretty certain that they're not going to want to have you fiddling around on their machines installing unknown (to them) libraries. In any case, you would have to do it for every individual machine.

The bottom line is that realistically this is not going to be an option. Your best bet is to give up trying to make IE6 do fancy stuff, and go back to using background images for your gradients. It's not pleasant to write, but there is a reason why everyone used to do it that way when IE6 was the standard browser.

Comment: But your *real* best bet is to never take jobs where IE 6 is a requirement! ;)

Comment: @Stephen P - heh, yeah, very much agree with that!! to be fair though, IE7 and IE8 would also suffer from the same problem if those DLLs were missing.

Comment: I think this is the problem but like you said, they aren't prepared to let me do anything to their machines so I'm going to have to go back to basics! Thanks for the help

Comment: People with older Browsers don't expect modern stuff, so go with old techniques for older browsers and newer techniques for new browsers